# Adding pre tag after onload doesn't take effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pre

I am trying an Jquery plugin for drawing arrows, as described [here](http://www.headjump.de/article/arrows-and-boxes)

The plugin causes this code

```
<pre class="arrows-and-boxes"> (Src) > (Target) </pre>
```

to look like this : Src --> Target

If I invoke this code before onload function, it works fine. But after(or within) the onload function, the format doesn't apply.

```
$("#canvas").append("<pre class=\"arrows-and-boxes\"> (Src) > (Target) </pre>");
```

I have raised the same question [here](http://www.headjump.de/article/arrows-and-boxes) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin creates a jQuery function called `.arrows_and_boxes()`. If you call this on the newly created element it should work:

```
var $newPre = $("<pre class=\"arrows-and-boxes\"> (User) > (Admin) </pre>");
$("#canvas").append($newPre)
$newPre.arrows_and_boxes();
```

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/1p7hz799/3/

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is this specific to pre tag? I could not understand how this works before ready function.

Comment: It's specific to the plugin. If you look at the [last 4 lines of the code](https://github.com/headjump/arrows-and-boxes/blob/master/js/arrowsandboxes.js#L844) you will see that it processes the ones currently on the page in the `document ready` event. Also, I should warn you that the plugin is [marked deprecated](https://github.com/headjump/arrows-and-boxes/blob/master/README.textile).